# Power calculations for starter motor designing

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, power, power-transmission

Let's consider an IC engine standard type motorcycle. What is the power needed from the starter motor to start it's engine? Please make all the calculations by taking suitable assumptions like the piston masses, etc. And considering power losses in transmission too

Comment: Well, first count the cylinders: 1, 2, 3, or 4. Use the kuckstart to measure the force required...

Comment: Let's calculate for only 1 cylinder engine.

Comment: So, what was the force measured?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering.SE! Please visit the [tour] page to know more about what type of questions can be asked here and what type of information you have to provide along with a question. Please add additional information directly in the question using the [edit] link rather than adding information to the comments.